# React Native: Triggering Animation on hide

Tags: animation, react-native

I have an element controlling the rendering of a child element. (A TouchableHighlight that sets some state in its `onPress`.) In the child element's `componentDidMount` method I construct an `Animated.spring` and `start` it. This works for entry, but I need to do the same animation in reverse to exit (it's like a drawer). `componentWillUnmount` executes too quickly for `Animated.spring` to even start working.

How would I handle animating the child's exit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have implemented a `FadeInOut` component that will animate a component in or out when its `isVisible` property changes. I made it because I wanted to avoid explicitly handling the visibility state in the components that should enter/exit with an animation.

```
<FadeInOut isVisible={this.state.someBooleanProperty} style={styles.someStyle}>
  <Text>Something...</Text>
</FadeInOut>
```

This implementation uses a delayed fade, because I use it for showing progress indicator, but you can change it to use any animation you want, or generalise it to accept the animation parameters as props:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react-native';

const {
  View,
  Animated,
  PropTypes
} = React;

export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'FadeInOut',
  propTypes: {
    isVisible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    style: View.propTypes.style
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      view: this.props.children,
      opacity: new Animated.Value(this.props.isVisible ? 1 : 0)
    };
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const isVisible = this.props.isVisible;
    const shouldBeVisible = nextProps.isVisible;

    if (isVisible && !shouldBeVisible) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        delay: 500,
        duration: 200
      }).start(this.removeView);
    }

    if (!isVisible && shouldBeVisible) {
      this.insertView();
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        delay: 500,
        duration: 200
      }).start();
    }
  },

  insertView() {
    this.setState({
      view: this.props.children
    });
  },

  removeView() {
    this.setState({
      view: null
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        pointerEvents={this.props.isVisible ? 'auto' : 'none'}
        style={[this.props.style, {opacity: this.state.opacity}]}>
        {this.state.view}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the animation ownership inverted.  If you move your animation logic to the parent that is opening and closing the child, the problem becomes much simpler.  Rather than beginning the animation on `componentDidMount`, do it on the click of your TouchableHighlight in addition to, but independent of, whatever prop manipulations on the child you need to do.

Then when the user clicks to close, you can simply reverse the animation as per normal and you don't really even need to unload it.  Also this would allow you to have a reusable drawer (the thing that slides up and down) and it's abstracted away from the content within it.  So you can have a single drawer mechanism supporting multiple different types of content.